# ufw status backup as a file

Tags: ufw

I can see the ufw status by typing and entering

> sudo ufw status

I want to back up this as a file. Where does this information reside in as a file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is in the files `/etc/ufw/user.rules` and `/etc/ufw/user6.rules` (although probably you should back up the whole of `/etc/ufw/`)

Ex.

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere                  
Samba                      ALLOW       Anywhere                  
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)             
Samba (v6)                 ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
```

corresponds to the IPv4 and IPv6 `RULES` sections as follows

```
$ sudo sed '/RULES/,/END RULES/!d' /etc/ufw/user{,6}.rules 
### RULES ###

### tuple ### allow tcp 22 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 in
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

### tuple ### allow udp 137,138 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 Samba - in
-A ufw-user-input -p udp -m multiport --dports 137,138 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment 'dapp_Samba'

### tuple ### allow tcp 139,445 0.0.0.0/0 any 0.0.0.0/0 Samba - in
-A ufw-user-input -p tcp -m multiport --dports 139,445 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment 'dapp_Samba'

### END RULES ###
### RULES ###

### tuple ### allow tcp 22 ::/0 any ::/0 in
-A ufw6-user-input -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

### tuple ### allow udp 137,138 ::/0 any ::/0 Samba - in
-A ufw6-user-input -p udp -m multiport --dports 137,138 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment 'dapp_Samba'

### tuple ### allow tcp 139,445 ::/0 any ::/0 Samba - in
-A ufw6-user-input -p tcp -m multiport --dports 139,445 -j ACCEPT -m comment --comment 'dapp_Samba'

### END RULES ###
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want your own rules and if you want them backed up the same as you entered them on the command line:

```
n=0
echo -n "" > ufw_backup
while [ 1 ]
do
  ((n++))
  we=$(ufw delete $n <<<"n" 2>/dev/null)
  if [ $? == 0 ]
  then
    we=$(sed -E "/Deleting:|Proceed with operation \(y\|n\)\? Aborted/d" <<<$we)
    echo "ufw$we" >>ufw_backup
  else
    break
  fi
done
cat ufw_backup
```

I am open for variants and improvements.

**The script can be dangerous. Don't change the "n" for "y" or you will delete all your rules.**